# How to package groups (with users in it) from one AEM instance to another?

Tags: aem

I need to package the groups/users withe their permissions to AEM 6.1 to 6.3. I have synced up the users through LDAP and used ACS ACLPackager to move groups and their permissions.

So now I have all the groups and their permissions in the new environment. And I have all the users as well through the Ldap.

Is there any way to assign the groups to the users directly as they were in the source instance, so that I don't need to assign them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have synced up the users through LDAP

With LDAP synch, I am assuming you are not synchronising the groups for the users because

> and used ACS ACLPackager to move groups and their permissions

The problem with this approach is that both groups and users are imported in two separate phases. Any binding between them will be lost naturally because your LDAP setup is unaware of user group bindings and the ACL packager is unaware of users within the groups.

Your best options are:

- Use ACL packager to migrate **BOTH** users and the user groups.
  OR
- Use LDAP to synchronise the users and user groups. I doubt this is possible in your setup if LDAP is unaware of user group permissions.

I practice, LDAP user mapping should be designed to be reentrant in AEM (depends on configuration) and the groups should also be mapped form LDAP. The group permissions can be handled with ACL packager. This setup allows seamless migration. If your LDAP setup allows user identifier to be some unique repeatable thing like email address then you can probably migrate all the users with ACL packager and let LDAP rebind them. This will require testing in your setup but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

ACS commons has a nice ACL packages that will copy all ACL entries (including users and groups) find it here: https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/packagers/acl-packager/index.html